# Importing data from website with subscription

Tags: google-sheets, data-scrubbing

The website I import data from is now subscription-based, I have a subscription but HTML import function doesn't pull data.

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.footballoutsiders.com/premium/defense-vs-receivers?year=2018&offense_defense=offense","table",1)
```

I updated the URL since it changed, and when I did, it returns an error.

> Could not fetch URL: https://www.footballoutsiders.com/premium/defense-vs-receivers?year=2018&offense_defense=offense

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTHTML only is able to get data from public web pages. One alternative is to use the UrlFetchApp from Google Apps Script.